# count of duplicate elements in an array in php

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

Hi,
   How can we find the count of duplicate elements in a `multidimensional array` ?

I have an array like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [lid] => 192
            [lname] => sdsss
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [lid] => 202
            [lname] =>  testing
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [lid] => 192
            [lname] => sdsss
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [lid] => 202
            [lname] =>  testing
        )

)
```

How to find the count of each elements ?

i.e, count of entries with id `192`,`202` etc

Comment: Simply loop in each and create a new array with `lid` as key and  increment (`++`) as value.

Comment: Does it matter what key under the values are? or it count as duplicate if the same value is under various different keys?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can adopt this trick; map each item of the array (which is an array itself) to its respective `['lid']` member and then use `array_count_value()` to do the counting for you.

```
array_count_values(array_map(function($item) {
    return $item['lid'];
}, $arr);
```

Plus, it's a one-liner, thus adding to elite hacker status.

#### Update

Since 5.5 you can shorten it to:

```
array_count_values(array_column($arr, 'lid'));
```

Comment: "_adding to elite hacker status_"! LOL! +1

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach ($array as $value) 
{
    $numbers[$value[lid]]++;
}
foreach ($numbers as $key => $value) 
{
    echo 'numbers of '.$key.' equal '.$value.'<br/>';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Following code will count duplicate element of an array.Please review it and try this code

```
 $arrayChars=array("green","red","yellow","green","red","yellow","green");

    $arrLength=count($arrayChars);
    $elementCount=array();
  for($i=0;$i<$arrLength-1;$i++)
    {
       $key=$arrayChars[$i];
      if($elementCount[$key]>=1)
       {
          $elementCount[$key]++;
       } else  {
          $elementCount[$key]=1;
       }


   }

   echo "<pre>";
   print_r($elementCount);
```

OUTPUT:
  Array
 (
    [green] => 3
    [red] => 2
    [yellow] => 2
 )

You can also view similar questions with array handling on following link
http://solvemyquest.com/count-duplicant-element-array-php-without-using-built-function/

Answer (score 0):

The following code will get the counts for all of them - anything > 1 at the end will be repeated.

```
<?php
$lidCount = array();
$lnameCount = array();

foreach ($yourArray as $arr) {

  if (isset($lidCount[$arr['lid']])) {
    $lidCount[$arr['lid']]++;
  } else {
    $lidCount[$arr['lid']] = 1;
  }

  if (isset($lnameCount [$arr['lname']])) {
    $lnameCount [$arr['lname']]++;
  } else {
    $lnameCount [$arr['lname']] = 1;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = array('192', '202', '192', '202');
print_r(array_count_values($array));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$orders = array(
 array(
    'lid' => '',
    'lname' => '',

  ))....
$foundIds = array();
foreach ( $orders as $index => $order )
{
  if ( isset( $foundIds[$order['lid']] ) )
  {
    $orders[$index]['is_dupe'] = true;
    $orders[$foundIds[$order['lid']]]['is_dupe'] = true;
  } else {
    $orders[$index]['is_dupe'] = false;
  }
  $foundIds[$order['lid']] = $index;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
$array_count = array();
foreach ($array as $arr) :
    if (in_array($arr, $array_count)) {
        foreach ($array_count as $key => $count) :
            if ($key == $arr) {
                $array_count[$key]++;
                break;
            }
        endforeach;
    } else {
        $array_count[$arr] = 1;
    }
endforeach;
```

Answer (score 0):

Check with `in_array()` function.