# PHP Count Duplicate Total Link

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

how can i count the total duplicate link in the array?

its similar question here: [count of duplicate elements in an array in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13413465/count-of-duplicate-elements-in-an-array-in-php)

but im not sure how to implement the code on my case.
my server PHP version 5.4

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [link] => http://myexample.com
            [total] => 3
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [link] => http://myexampledomain.com
            [total] => 2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [link] => http://myexample.com
            [total] => 1
        )
)
```

I am expecting the result to be:

```
http://myexample.com: 4
http://myotherdomain.com: 2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use

```
$result = [];
array_walk($arr, function($v, $k)use(&$result) {
    if (isset($result[$v['link']])) {
        $result[$v['link']] += $v['total'];
    }else{
        $result[$v['link']] = $v['total'];
    }
});
print_r($result);
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/446982)

Comment: @Uchiha it should count the total as well. how can i count the total?

Comment: @tonoslfx Try it out my answer they work for you or not?

Answer (score 2):

Try below code:

```
<?php
$array = array(array("link" => "http://myexample.com", "total" => 3), array("link" => "http://myexampledomain.com", "total" => 2), array("link" => "http://myexample.com", "total" => 1));
$res = array();
foreach ($array as $vals) {
    if (array_key_exists($vals['link'], $res)) {
        $res[$vals['link']]+=$vals['total'];
    } else {
        $res[$vals['link']]=$vals['total'];
    }
}
print_r($res);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this simple logic :

```
$tempArray = array();
foreach ($array as $value) {
    if (!array_key_exists($value['link'],$tempArray) {
        $tempArray[$value['link']] = 1;
    } else {
        $tempArray[$value['link']] = $tempArray['link'] + 1;
    }
}

print_r($tempArray);
```