# Get Count of particular entity in array inside array?

Tags: php, arrays, count

I have an array named hello as follows,

```
hello(
    0 => ([name => abc, add=>def, city=>ny,phone=>12345]);
    1 => ([name => pqr, add=>mno, city=>qw,phone=>67890]);
    2 => ([name => abc, add=>def, city=>ny,phone=>14785]);
    3 => ([name => ghi, add=>foo, city=>yu,phone=>258]);
    4 => ([name => jkl, add=>exy, city=>ny,phone=>95145]);
);
```

It has few elements and that elements are also array itself, like while retring query result.
I want to count a perticular name that repeats. Like in hello[0] and hello[2], so my ans should be abc=2.

How can I do that?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [count of duplicate elements in an array in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13413465/count-of-duplicate-elements-in-an-array-in-php)

Comment: (What did you try?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit 2:**
Now you want a way to count all of the objects:

```
$arr = [
    0 => (object) ['name' => 'abc', 'add'=>'def', 'city'=>'ny', 'phone'=>'12345'],
    1 => (object) ['name' => 'pqr', 'add'=>'mno', 'city'=>'qw', 'phone'=>'67890'],
    2 => (object) ['name' => 'abc', 'add'=>'def', 'city'=>'ny', 'phone'=>'14785'],
    3 => (object) ['name' => 'ghi', 'add'=>'foo', 'city'=>'yu', 'phone'=>'258'],
    4 => (object) ['name' => 'jkl', 'add'=>'exy', 'city'=>'ny', 'phone'=>'95145'],
];

function countBy (callable $f, $xs) {
  return array_reduce($xs, function ($acc, $x) use ($f) {
    $y = call_user_func($f, $x);
    $acc[$y] = isset($acc[$y]) ? $acc[$y] + 1 : 1;
    return $acc;
  }, []);
}

json_encode(countBy (function ($x) { return $x->name; }, $arr));
// => { "abc": 2, "pqr": 1, "ghi": 1, "jkl": 1 }
```

---

**Edit:**
You lied about the data types so I changed `$x['name']` to `$x->name` and `$x[$attr]` to `$x->{$name}`

---

You can use `array_reduce`

```
array_reduce($arr, function ($acc, $x) {
  return $x->name === 'abc' ? $acc + 1 : $acc;
}, 0);
// => 2
```

Or write it as a function

```
function countAttr($attr, $match, $xs) {
  return array_reduce($xs, function ($acc, $x) use ($attr, $match) {
    return $x->{$attr} === $match ? $acc + 1 : $acc;
  }, 0);
}

countAttr('name', 'abc', $arr)(
// => 2
```

Comment: it will work, but the array is dynamic so, i can't specify " === abc".

Comment: Ok I provided a function use too

Comment: returns array "  Cannot use object of type stdClass as array "

Comment: Well you said they were arrays, not `stdClass` objects. In that case, see my edit.

Comment: ok thnks, it works. Now can you tell me if i want to compare all of them with each other and wanted to get final result of all count of all values. thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

In this case defining a `function` would be best so that count for any name cen be get. You can try this -

```
$array = [
    0 => ['name' => 'abc', 'add'=>'def', 'city'=>'ny','phone'=>'12345'],
    1 => ['name' => 'pqr', 'add'=>'mno', 'city'=>'qw','phone'=>'67890'],
    2 => ['name' => 'abc', 'add'=>'def', 'city'=>'ny','phone'=>'14785'],
    3 => ['name' => 'ghi', 'add'=>'foo', 'city'=>'yu','phone'=>'258'],
    4 => ['name' => 'jkl', 'add'=>'exy', 'city'=>'ny','phone'=>'95145'],
];
function get_name_count($array, $name)
{  
    // filter array for name
    $temp = array_filter($array, function($a) use($name) {
        return ($a['name'] === $name);
    });
    // return count
    return count($temp);
}

var_dump(get_name_count($array, 'abc'));
```

**Output**

```
int(2)
```

Comment: He/she lied about the input data so this will fail for the same reason my original answer did. Nice answer otherwise ^_^

Comment: I guess so too. :)

Answer (score -1):

```
// hello , please use some standard name for array 
// code not tested 
// define variable if required 
$field_name="name";
$value="abc";
$count=0;
echo count_field($field_name,$value);
function count_field($field_name,$value)
{
 foreach($hello as $val)
 {
   if($val[$field_name]==$value)
   {
   $count++;
   }
 }
 return $count;
}
```