# COUNT occurence in array php

Tags: php, arrays, count

I have a php array, and I want to count how many item by id exist an increment the count_giga_winz attribute by occurrence

```
array(
(int) 0 => array(
    'g' => array(
        'id' => '13',
        'photoCadeau' => 'gigawinz-mini-cooper.jpg',
        'photoDetail' => 'giga2-hover.png'
    ),
    (int) 0 => array(
        'count_giga_winz' => '1'
    )
),
(int) 1 => array(
    'g' => array(
        'id' => '14',
        'photoCadeau' => 'w3.jpg',
        'photoDetail' => 'w3.jpg'
    ),
    (int) 0 => array(
        'count_giga_winz' => '1'
    )
),
(int) 2 => array(
    'g' => array(
        'id' => '14',
        'photoCadeau' => 'w3.jpg',
        'photoDetail' => 'w3.jpg'
    ),
    (int) 0 => array(
        'count_giga_winz' => '1'
    )
)
)
```

I want to count that by id, I see the duplicated question but it didn't work for me

Comment: Do you have any examples of what you have tried already? You should be able to simply use a `for` loop and count where `item_array[i][0][0] == $match_val`. Also, the placement of `count_giga_winz` doesn't seem to provide any benefit, or maybe you need to provide a larger sample set of your array contents as well as an example of what you are looking for as your results.

Comment: Read through: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask any update your question with more details.

Comment: You said you've seen another question but it didn't help you - how didn't it help i.e. what did you try that didn't work?

Comment: Yes, if you found a similar question that didn't help, it may help us if you include a link to that question and an explanation as to why that one didn't help you out.

Comment: I was tried this solution [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13413465/count-of-duplicate-elements-in-an-array-in-php]

Comment: @MALKIMOHAMED please edit your question, add the link to that other question, and provide some details on why that will not work for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you friends I solve the problem by using this code:

```
        $tpl_1= array();
        $tpl= array();
        foreach ($gigawinzs as $keys => $values) {
            $tpl_1[$keys] = array(
                'id'=>$values['g']['id'],
                'photoDetail' => $values['g']['photoDetail'],
                'photoCadeau'=>$values['g']['photoCadeau'],
                'count_giga_winz' => $values[0]['count_giga_winz']
            );
        }
        $sumArray = array();

        foreach ($tpl_1 as $k=>$subArray) {
            @$sumArray[$subArray['id']]+=$subArray['count_giga_winz'];
            $tpl[$subArray['id']] = array(
                'id'=>$subArray['id'],
                'photoDetail' => $subArray['photoDetail'],
                'photoCadeau'=>$subArray['photoCadeau'],
                'count_giga_winz' => $sumArray[$subArray['id']]
            );
        }
```