# Count elements with a the same name in an array in php

Tags: php, arrays, pdo

So I have this array:

[image]

I don't know if it's clear, but there are alot of elemenst in this array that have the same name, I want to count this elements and show it, this is how I create the array:

```
 foreach ($rowa as $rowsa)
{
    $sql = "SELECT count(*) as NUMBER FROM BANDZENDINGEN WHERE FB_AFGESLOTEN = 'F' AND FB_AKTIEF = 'T' AND FI_AFVOERKANAAL = 1 AND FI_RAYONID = $rowsa  AND FI_VERRIJKINGID < 1;";
    $sfh = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    $sfh->execute();
    $row = $sfh->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 0);

    array_push($row, $rows['FC_RAYON']);
    print_r($row);

}
```

I already have tried this:

[count of duplicate elements in an array in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13413465/count-of-duplicate-elements-in-an-array-in-php)

This anwser doesn't seem to work for me, but maybe I am doing something wrong.

btw $rows['FC_RAYON'] is from another query, it's not relevant to this question, but if you want to see it I will edit my post to show it.

So must I do? could you please help.

EDIT

better look at the array:

```
 Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => RT-SCB-PB01 ) 
 Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => RT-SCB-PB01 ) 
 Array ( [0] => 3 [1] => RT-SCB-PB01 ) 
 Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => ASDC-PBSN ) 
 Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => ASDC-PBSN ) 
 Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => ASDC-PBSN ) 
 Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => ASDC-PBSN ) 
 Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => ASDW-PBSN )
```

This is a very small part of the array.

EDIT 2

```
 Array
(
  [0] => 2
  [1] => RT-SCB-PB01
)

 Array
(
  [0] => 2
  [1] => RT-SCB-PB01
)

Array
(
  [0] => 1
  [1] => RT-SCB-PB01
)

Array
(
  [0] => 3
  [1] => RT-SCB-PB01
)

Array
(
  [0] => 2
  [1] => ASDC-PBSN
)

Array
(
  [0] => 2
  [1] => ASDC-PBSN
)

Array
(
  [0] => 1
  [1] => ASDC-PBSN
)

Array
(
  [0] => 1
  [1] => ASDW-PBSN
)

Array
(
  [0] => 0
  [1] => ASDW-PBSN
)

Array
(
  [0] => 0
  [1] => ASDW-PBSN
)
```

so this is here is an even beter look at the array, the data in the array is diffrent because it's is a very actief database

EDIT 3

if your intersted this is my entire result you can see it here:

https://mega.nz/#!uvpBWSoL!V6xYCuJ5mCWwiYqnoaz6LiYynioCylWDxPYioV_9qpo
open with paint

Comment: Please give a simple example of the array and in text

Comment: If your data is coming from the database it feels like you should be getting your final result through a query directly rather than loading everything and filtering.

Comment: what exactly do you want to count?

Comment: @AndreiFiordean I want to count the duplicates so RT-SCB-PB01 would be 5 and ASDC-PBSN 2.

Comment: please post another picture of your array but print it like this:
`echo '<pre>';
print_r($row);
echo '</pre>';
die;`

this way you will have it pretty

Comment: @AndreiFiordean sure will do

Comment: @nordin ok mate, waiting for the pic, thank you

Comment: The query, with which you create the array you show to us, does only have one selected column. In the output there are two columns. This must have to do with `$rows['FC_RAYON']`, but the code for that is missing and it doesn't seem to make much sense, given the output. I agree with @apokryfos that a direct query is the best solution, but given the above I cannot create it.

Comment: ok so i would recommend as well to resolve this issue in the SQL, but if you do want to resolve it in another way(it will use up memory), you could make another foreach after you create the row, and manually count each entry

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[array_count_values](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php)

array_count_values() returns an array using the values of array as keys and their frequency in array as values.

```
$varArray = array(); // take a one empty array

foreach ($rowa as $rowsa)
{
    $sql = "SELECT count(*) as NUMBER FROM BANDZENDINGEN WHERE FB_AFGESLOTEN = 'F' AND FB_AKTIEF = 'T' AND FI_AFVOERKANAAL = 1 AND FI_RAYONID = $rowsa  AND FI_VERRIJKINGID < 1;";
    $sfh = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    $sfh->execute();
    $row = $sfh->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 0);

    array_push($row, $rows['FC_RAYON']);
    //print_r($row);
    //array_push($varArray,$rows['FC_RAYON']); // Also May I think $rows['FC_RAYON'] is give value like RT-SCB-PB01,ASDC-PBSN etc.
    array_push($varArray,$row[1]); // I have push the send value of array like RT-SCB-PB01,ASDC-PBSN etc. and make in single array.
}

$dupArrays = array_count_values($varArray); // It will return Counts all the values of an array
echo 'Total No Items: '.count($dupArrays).'<br><br>';
echo "<pre>";
print_r($dupArrays);
echo "</pre>";
```

The output will be :

```
Total No Items: 3

Array
(
    [RT-SCB-PB01] => 3 // Count of duplicate value of RT-SCB-PB01 is 3
    [ASDC-PBSN] => 4 // Count of duplicate value of ASDC-PBSN is 3
    [ASDW-PBSN] => 1 // Count of duplicate value of ASDW-PBSN is 3
)
```

Get using foreach method

```
foreach($dupArrays as $key => $value){
    echo $key.' Count '.$value.' times.';
    echo "<br>";
}
```

Output:

```
RT-SCB-PB01 Count 3 times.
ASDC-PBSN Count 4 times.
ASDW-PBSN Count 1 times.
```

Comment: @nordin, want you like this logic?

Comment: this works, thanks for the help. Do you also know how to echo it properly?

Comment: Using the foreach method you can echo it.

Comment: well I tried that and it only showed the numbers not the names.

Comment: @nordin I have updated an answer. use array key. now you can get an idea.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191711/discussion-between-r-p-and-nordin).

Answer (score 0):

couldn't you just do a single query like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT FI_RAYONID,COUNT(FI_RAYONID) as NUMBER 
    FROM BANDZENDINGEN 
    WHERE FB_AFGESLOTEN = 'F' 
    AND FB_AKTIEF = 'T' 
    AND FI_AFVOERKANAAL = 1  
    AND FI_VERRIJKINGID < 1 
    GROUP BY FI_RAYONID ;";
$sfh = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$sfh->execute();
$result = $sfh->fetch(PDO::FETCH_KEY_PAIR);
```

then $result becomes a keyed array of the id and the counts so you can work with it much more simply