# Create and array using values from another array but only when the value appears a certain number of times

Tags: php, arrays

I'm hoping someone can help.

I have values in an array.. Let's say

```
$array = ("BMW", "BMW", "BMW", "AUDI", "AUDI", "FORD", "FORD", "FORD");
```

So I want to count the values. I can do that using `array_count_values ($array);`

This creates another array containing `BMW => 3, AUDI => 2, FORD => 3`

So what I want to do now is move BMW & FORD into another array because they occurred three times and leave AUDI behind.

Any ideas?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome! Stack Overflow is *not* a code writing service. 
We are always glad to help and support new coders but you need to help yourself first. 
You are expected to try to write the code yourself.
Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and 
[How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: You want only the brands that occurred most frequent?

Comment: Loop again on them and collect them in a different array?

Comment: this would give you a hint https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55646668/count-elements-with-a-the-same-name-in-an-array-in-php/55647562

Answer (score 1):

Since everyone is throwing around answers let me also not miss out.... In case you want only those brands that occur most frequent in `$array` you can simply use an array_filter to filter those that match the maximum number of occurrences. Finally you can extract those keys to obtain the brands through array_keys.

```
<?php

$array = array("BMW", "BMW", "BMW", "AUDI", "AUDI", "FORD", "FORD", "FORD");
$frequencies = array_count_values($array);
$max = max(array_values($frequencies));

// If you don't want to do this dynamically you can simply change the
// filter condition of course.
$filtered = array_filter($frequencies, function ($val) use ($max) {
    // Since you mentioned you work with hard coded values,
    // you could change it to
    // return $val >= 3;
    return $val === $max;
});

$filteredBrands = array_keys($filtered);
$allBrands = array_keys($frequencies);
// We can then exclude the filtered set
// from the entire set to separate them
// into two sets.
$difference = array_diff($allBrands, $filteredBrands);

print_r($filteredBrands);
echo '</br>';
print_r($difference);
echo '</br>';
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will help you 
First add the the element that we want in a new array (`$newArray`) 
Then use the `array_diff` and update the first array

```
<?php

$array = ["BMW", "BMW", "BMW", "AUDI", "AUDI", "FORD", "FORD", "FORD"];
$countArray = (array_count_values ($array));

function youCondition($countArray, $element) {
    return $countArray[$element] == 3;
}

$newArray = [];
for ($i=0; $i < count($array); $i++) { 
    // put any condition that you want here
    if (youCondition($countArray, $array[$i])) {
        $newArray[] = $array[$i];
    } 
}

// your new generated array
print_r($newArray);
$array = array_diff($array, $newArray);

// your updated array
print_r($array);
```

**output**

```
Array
(
    [0] => BMW
    [1] => BMW
    [2] => BMW
    [3] => FORD
    [4] => FORD
    [5] => FORD
)
Array
(
    [3] => AUDI
    [4] => AUDI
)
```

And you can change your condition (`$countArray[$array[$i]] == 3`) and make the different arrays

Comment: If you hard code the count of 3 this way you might as well hard code the arrays from the start.... Also OP didn't clearly specify what a general solution would look like so how can you answer on this.

Comment: I make it more dynamic now

Comment: Thank you so much! I've changed the == to > for my needs and it works perfectly. ;-)

Comment: You're welcome , if my answer helped you with your question, I would appreciate it if you choose it as the best answer as you wish.